# how do I run gulp with error globalThis is not defined

Tags: wordpress, npm, gulp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl31f.png)

Please help.  Trying to run npm install and then gulp but keep getting the error as shown in the picture.  Managed to run gulp yesterday?